# Filter an array of objects by one key and show another

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter out questions based on the difficulty that is set to the question in the array. So when I check the box at the beginning of the quiz it will display the question based on the difficulty it has been assigned. I think I have the filter right but I don't know how to display the question. This is the code I have written.

```
let questionE1 = document.getElementById("question")
let a_answer = document.getElementById("a-answer");
let b_answer = document.getElementById("b-answer");
let c_answer = document.getElementById("c-answer");
let d_answer = document.getElementById("d-answer");
let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

let currentQuiz = 0;

let easyDifficulty = document.getElementById("easy-diff");
let mediumDifficulty = document.getElementById("medium-diff");
let hardDifficulty = document.getElementById("hard-diff");
let difficulty = document.querySelectorAll('[name="difficulty"]');
let difficultyLevel = "";

let questionE1 = document.getElementById("question")
let a_answer = document.getElementById("a-answer");
let b_answer = document.getElementById("b-answer");
let c_answer = document.getElementById("c-answer");
let d_answer = document.getElementById("d-answer");
let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

let questions = [
    {
        question: `What is the biggest city in the USA`,
        a: `Chicago`,
        b: `Los Angeles`,
        c: `Boston`,
        d: `New York`,
        answer: `d`,
        difficulty:`hard`
    },

    {
        question: `What is the longest river on the earth`,
        a: `Amazon`,
        b: `Nile`,
        c: `Amur`,
        d: `Mississippi`,
        answer: `b`,
        difficulty:`medium`
    },

    {
        question: `What is the highest mountain on earth`,
        a: `Everest`,
        b: `K2`,
        c: `Broad Peak`,
        d: `Manaslu`,
        answer: `a`,
        difficulty:`easy`
    },
]

let filteredQuestions  = questions.filter(question => question.difficulty === difficultyLevel)

let pickDifficulty = () => {
    if (easyDifficulty.checked){
        difficultyLevel = "easy";
    } else if (mediumDifficulty.checked){
        difficultyLevel = "medium";
    }else if (hardDifficulty.checked){
        difficultyLevel = "hard";
    }
}


function getQuestion() {

    if (pickDifficulty === "easy") {
        return filteredQuestions.value;
    } else if (pickDifficulty === "medium"){
        return filteredQuestions.value;
    } else if (pickDifficulty === "hard"){
        return filteredQuestions.value;
    }
}

displayQuestion ()

function displayQuestion () {

    let currentQuestion = questions[currentQuiz]

    questionE1.innerText = currentQuestion.question
    a_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.a
    b_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.b
    c_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.c
    d_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.d
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the Dom you are trying to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems.

`difficultyLevel` is not assigned a usable value before used in the declaration of `filteredQuestions`. One solution is to make it function, to be called later.

Also, `pickDifficulty` is declared as a function, but later referred to without execution:

```
if (pickDifficulty === "easy") {
```

(This may be a typo, and the intention was to compare it to the global variable `difficultyLevel`.)

And, when referring to `filteredQuestions`, a non-existent property, `value`, is called:

```
return filteredQuestions.value;
```

Along with that, as the return value of the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function it would be an array, not an object. So:

```
let filteredQuestions = questions.filter(...)
```

...assigns an array to `filteredQuestions`.

```js
//let currentQuiz = 0;

let easyDifficulty = document.getElementById("easy-diff");
let mediumDifficulty = document.getElementById("medium-diff");
let hardDifficulty = document.getElementById("hard-diff");
let difficulty = document.querySelectorAll('[name="difficulty"]');
let difficultyLevel = "";

let questionE1 = document.getElementById("question")
let a_answer = document.getElementById("a-answer");
let b_answer = document.getElementById("b-answer");
let c_answer = document.getElementById("c-answer");
let d_answer = document.getElementById("d-answer");
//let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

let questions = [
    {
        question: `What is the biggest city in the USA`,
        a: `Chicago`,
        b: `Los Angeles`,
        c: `Boston`,
        d: `New York`,
        answer: `d`,
        difficulty:`hard`
    },

    {
        question: `What is the longest river on the earth`,
        a: `Amazon`,
        b: `Nile`,
        c: `Amur`,
        d: `Mississippi`,
        answer: `b`,
        difficulty:`medium`
    },

    {
        question: `What is the highest mountain on earth`,
        a: `Everest`,
        b: `K2`,
        c: `Broad Peak`,
        d: `Manaslu`,
        answer: `a`,
        difficulty:`easy`
    },
]

let filteredQuestions = (difficultyLevel) => { 
    return questions.filter(question => question.difficulty === difficultyLevel);
}

/*
let pickDifficulty = () => {

    if (easyDifficulty.checked){
        return "easy";
    } else if (mediumDifficulty.checked){
        return "medium";
    } else if (hardDifficulty.checked){
        return "hard";
    }
} */


function getQuestion (diff) {

    if (diff === "easy") {
        return filteredQuestions(diff); //.value;
    } else if (diff === "medium"){
        return filteredQuestions(diff); //.value;
    } else if (diff === "hard"){
        return filteredQuestions(diff); //.value;
    }
    return [{}];
}

function displayQuestion ({target: diff}) {

    //let currentQuestion = questions[currentQuiz]
        let question = getQuestion(diff.value);
    questionE1.innerText = question[0].question
    a_answer.innerText = question[0].a
    b_answer.innerText = question[0].b
    c_answer.innerText = question[0].c
    d_answer.innerText = question[0].d
}

difficulty.forEach(diff => diff.addEventListener("change", displayQuestion));
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easy-diff" value="easy"> easy<br>
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="medium-diff" value="medium"> medium<br>
<input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="hard-diff" value="hard"> hard<br>

<div id="question"></div>
<div id="a-answer"></div>
<div id="b-answer"></div>
<div id="c-answer"></div>
<div id="d-answer"></div>
```

Comment: If I was to keep adding questions to the array with different difficulty will the above code still work?

Comment: I wrote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74200731/2743458) that adds capability for multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to fixing the question code. This time making fewer changes the code, and, more importantly, adding the ability to have multiple questions, at each level, displayed.

```js
let currentQuiz = 0;

let easyDifficulty = document.getElementById("easy-diff");
let mediumDifficulty = document.getElementById("medium-diff");
let hardDifficulty = document.getElementById("hard-diff");
//let difficulty = document.querySelectorAll('[name="difficulty"]');
let difficulty = document.getElementById("difficulty");
let difficultyLevel = "";

let questionE1 = document.querySelector(".question")
let a_answer = document.querySelector(".a-answer");
let b_answer = document.querySelector(".b-answer");
let c_answer = document.querySelector(".c-answer");
let d_answer = document.querySelector(".d-answer");
//let submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

let questions = [{
    question: `What is the biggest city in the USA`,
    a: `Chicago`,
    b: `Los Angeles`,
    c: `Boston`,
    d: `New York`,
    answer: `d`,
    difficulty: `hard`
  },

  {
    question: `What is the longest river on the earth`,
    a: `Amazon`,
    b: `Nile`,
    c: `Amur`,
    d: `Mississippi`,
    answer: `b`,
    difficulty: `medium`
  },

  {
    question: `What is the highest mountain on earth`,
    a: `Everest`,
    b: `K2`,
    c: `Broad Peak`,
    d: `Manaslu`,
    answer: `a`,
    difficulty: `easy`
  },

  {
    question: `2nd`,
    a: `Everest`,
    b: `K2`,
    c: `Broad Peak`,
    d: `Manaslu`,
    answer: `a`,
    difficulty: `easy`
  },
]

//let filteredQuestions  = questions.filter(question => question.difficulty === difficultyLevel)

let pickDifficulty = () => {
  if (easyDifficulty.checked) {
    difficultyLevel = "easy";
  } else if (mediumDifficulty.checked) {
    difficultyLevel = "medium";
  } else if (hardDifficulty.checked) {
    difficultyLevel = "hard";
  }
}

/*
function getQuestion() {

  if (pickDifficulty === "easy") {
    return filteredQuestions.value;
  } else if (pickDifficulty === "medium") {
    return filteredQuestions.value;
  } else if (pickDifficulty === "hard") {
    return filteredQuestions.value;
  }
}
*/

displayQuestion()

function displayQuestion() {

  let currentQuestion = questions[currentQuiz]

  questionE1.innerText = currentQuestion.question
  a_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.a
  b_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.b
  c_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.c
  d_answer.innerText = currentQuestion.d
}

difficulty.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  pickDifficulty()
  const filteredQuestions = questions.filter(question => question.difficulty === difficultyLevel)

  const quiztemplate = document.querySelectorAll('.quiz')
  const quizparent = quiztemplate[0].parentNode
  quiztemplate.forEach((qq => quizparent.removeChild(qq)))


  filteredQuestions.forEach((quiz) => {
    const quizquestion = quizparent.appendChild(quiztemplate[0].cloneNode(true));
    quizquestion.querySelector(".question").innerText = quiz.question
    quizquestion.querySelector(".a-answer").innerText = quiz.a
    quizquestion.querySelector(".b-answer").innerText = quiz.b
    quizquestion.querySelector(".c-answer").innerText = quiz.c
    quizquestion.querySelector(".d-answer").innerText = quiz.d
  })
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="difficulty">
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="easy-diff" value="easy"> easy<br>
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="medium-diff" value="medium"> medium<br>
  <input type="radio" name="difficulty" id="hard-diff" value="hard"> hard<br>
</div><br>

<div class="quiz">
  <div class="question"></div>
  <div class="a-answer"></div>
  <div class="b-answer"></div>
  <div class="c-answer"></div>
  <div class="d-answer"></div><br>
</div>
```